# ms dynamics crm 365 turn off or disable "View Alerts" notification message

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to find a way to disable/turn off the "View Alerts" notification that appears when I launch CRM. Our CRM instance does not have the sales module installed (we do not use it) and the users do not use the outlook client.

As a result, when they click on "view alerts", nothing happens. It has been requested to suppress this notification completely. Is there someway I can do this? This is an online instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View Alerts** notifications coming from the core entity called **Trace** for server side sync failures. Try to remove the privileges (**Read**) for your users security role on this entity under core records tab.

[image]

[Read more](http://www.xrmcoaches.com/2015/02/system-wide-alerts-in-dynamics-crm-2015/)

Outlook client/App for outlook notifications & some other similar can be suppressed from system settings.

[image]

[Reference](https://dynamicsofdynamicscrm.com/2016/03/15/quick-tip-how-to-remove-message-notifications-in-dynamics-crm/)